# Unable to add Custom logs to Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

[image]

Hi All,
I am unable to add custom logs Log analytics -> Advanced Settings -> Data->Custom Logs though in the connected resource it's showing my machine connected. am I missing some thing?
PS : I am using azure trail account

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Custom Logs is in preview, you need enable it on OMS Portal firstly.

Firstly, click `OMS Portal`.

[image]

Then, enable `Custom Logs` feature.

[image]

Comment: I test in my lab, I get same result with you. When I enable the feature, I could use `Custom Logs`, if possible, I suggest you could try.

Comment: Did you check you have contributor access to Subscription/OMS worksspace?