# Azure Custom Logs general availability date

Tags: azure, azure-oms

As per OMS portal Azure Custom logs are in preview mode. I am not able to find any link, providing an expected date of general availability. Can neone help me with that ??

Also I am not able to find any link providing information on how to activate custom logs for a virtual machine scale set ? Other than log analytics? is there is any way to capture custom logs ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Custom Logs is in preview, you need enable it on OMS Portal firstly.

[image]

More information about this you could check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034162/unable-to-add-custom-logs-to-log-analytics/49041440#49041440).

If you want to collect log from VMSS, you need install oms agent on it. You could use CLI to do this, for Linux:

```
az vmss extension set --name OmsAgentForLinux --publisher Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring --resource-group <nameOfResourceGroup> --vmss-name <nameOfNodeType> --settings "{'workspaceId':'<OMSworkspaceId>'}" --protected-settings "{'workspaceKey':'<OMSworkspaceKey>'}"
```

For Windows:

```
az vmss extension set --name MicrosoftMonitoringAgent --publisher Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring --resource-group <nameOfResourceGroup> --vmss-name <nameOfNodeType> --settings "{'workspaceId':'<OMSworkspaceId>'}" --protected-settings "{'workspaceKey':'<OMSworkspaceKey>'}"
```

More information about Custom logs in Log Analytics you could check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-custom-logs).

Comment: I need a date for general availability and if there is any alternative to custom logs

Comment: If my understanding is right, now, custom log is in preview, you could enable it and use this function. But if you want to know date for general availability, you could open a ticket to Azure. I think the ticket is free. People here I think don't know specific time. Hope it helps.

Comment: What I am interested is the date on which custom log will be out of preview mode? and also to know if there is any existing alternative to custom logs

Comment: @BlindSniper Sorry, I also don't know the data, but I suggest you could open a ticket to ask Azure or give a feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics). As far as I know, Azure does not support other function to collect custom logs. If possible, I suggest you could enable custom logs and use it.

Comment: Hi, if you have other question, please let me know :--).