# How to enable Custom Logs for Azure Log Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to enable Custom Logs for Azure Log Analytics.

I looked at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-custom-logs) which says this:

After you are redirected to the OMS portal, click the Settings tile on the top right-hand side of the page.

[image: OMS portal Settings option]

I also found this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034162/unable-to-add-custom-logs-to-log-analytics) page which says a similar thing.

Now when I go to the OMS portal I see the following:

[image]

which no cog!

Has how to enable this moved or have I not got the correct access?

I am an Owner of the subscription but not account administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your issue, I created the workspace, I add a user as  **READONLY USER**.

[image]

In the portal of my own account(**ADMINISTRATOR** of the workspace), it will be fine. But in the portal of the **READONLY USER** , it is the same issue with yours.

You could refer to the screenshot.

[image]

So you should get the **CONTRIBUTOR** user to the workspace or create a workspace by yourself, it will be fine.

Comment: On the one subscription I am an `Onwer` and I can see the cog and on the other subscription I am a `Contributor` and I can't see the cog. I will get my subscription `Owner` to update this